# What can i do with a low And Old spec computer?

Tags: xubuntu, system-installation

I just rebuilt a computer, 512 Mbs of ram,180Gb,Intel Pentium 3,

should i install xubuntu? would it make it any faster?

i would like to use it for basic browsing,homework,All of that mostly online/In the cloud.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: its like 340 i think or 600 im not too sure. should i buy new ram cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just work - the specs are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Lightweight_GUI_alternative_.28Xubuntu_and_Lubuntu.29).

> Ubuntu Desktop Edition
>
> 1. 700 MHz processor *(about Intel Celeron or better)*
> 2. 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
> 3. 5 GB of hard-drive space *(or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)*
> 4. VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
> 5. Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
> 6. [Internet access](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Synaptic/PackageDownloadScript) is helpful

As long as the processor is somewhere above 500Mhz, it should work, just not very quickly.

Comment: its like 340 i think or 600 im not too sure. should i buy new ram cards? Or a new motherboard? or what?

Comment: More RAM would help a bit - but what it would probably need would be a bigger processor or a new Motherboard. I have tried running Xfce on a Raspberry Pi *(700MHz Processor + 512Mb of RAM - but very different hardware, though it has a similar operating system)* and it is *slow*. So it would go with your current hardware, but a bigger processor would ensure it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to ubuntu flavours, then try Lubuntu.  That generally runs well on lower spec, and will be quicker.  However, for real speed on such a machine give Puppy Linux a try.  Go on, don't be scared.  It's easy!